# Right aligned first column in a cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, cases, mathtools

Is there a simple way to obtain a right aligned first column in the `cases` environment. As far as I can see, `mathtools` does not add such an option.

(This question might be read as a request for enhancement on mathtools... :) )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) actually provides this extension as a feature already! Cases can be created using the following syntax:

```
\newcases{<case name>}{<space>}{%
  <left col align>}{<right col align>}{<left delim>}{<right delim>}
```

The regular `dcases` case is defined in the following way:

```
\newcases{dcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
```

Consequently, you would probably be interested in:

```
\makeatletter
\newcases{mycases}{\quad}{%
  \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother
```

[image: Modified cases]

Comment: Ah! This is not in the docs...

Comment: Remember to add `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after using this. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Since it require some knowledge to use, it is only used internally. Suggest a good name for it, and I might add it

Comment: @daleif: so did you add it?