# Removing brace from the left of dcases

Tags: cases

is it possible to remove brace from the left of following equation?

```
\begin{equation}
  a=
    \begin{dcases}
     1& r\geq 5,
     3& \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: the whole point of dcases is to add the brace. use `aligned`

Comment: Your readers won't be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aligned` or a regular `array` with the appropriate column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a =
    \begin{dcases}
      1 & r \geq 5, \\
      3 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
  \qquad
  b = 
    \begin{array}{ @{} r l @{} }
      1 & r \geq 5, \\[\jot]
      3 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
  \qquad
  c = 
    \begin{aligned}
      1 \quad & r \geq 5, \\
      3 \quad & \text{otherwise}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`array`s set their contents in `\textstyle` by default. Issue `\displaystyle` if needed, and perhaps also adjust the vertical gap `\\[\jot]` to a larger multiple.

Comment: There's a big difference between `dcases` and `array`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `\!` before `\begin{aligned}` in order to get the correct spacing?

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do it, but your readers won't be happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{nocases}
  {\quad}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
  {.}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a=
    \begin{nocases}
     1& r\geq 5, \\
     3& \text{otherwise}
    \end{nocases}
\qquad
  a=
    \begin{dcases}
     1& r\geq 5, \\
     3& \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HenriMenke: Old reference: [Right aligned first column in a `cases` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27520/5764)