# Function with cases or array

Tags: arrays, cases

I want to get this function:

[image]

I wrote two options, but I can't match the picture. Here is the first one:

```
\begin{displaymath}
        P[\chi_{n+1}=j|\chi_{n}=i]=
        \begin{dcases}
                \frac{N-i}{N}&\text{si }j=i+1\\
                \frac{i}{N}&\text{si }j=i-1\\
                0&\text{otro caso}
        \end{dcases}
\end{displaymath}
```

[image: Case 1]

And here is the second one: (This one is kind of compressed)

```
\begin{displaymath}
        P[\chi_{n+1}=j|\chi_{n}=i]=
        \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                \dfrac{N-i}{N} & \text{si }j=i+1\\
                \dfrac{i}{N} & \text{si }j=i-1\\
                0 & \text{en otro caso}
        \end{array}\right
\end{displaymath}
```

How can improve the code?. Thanks for the support.

Comment: What kind of "improvement" are you looking for?

Comment: A minor suggestion: Use `\mid` instead of `|` to denote conditioning on some event.

Comment: (Or `\newcommand{\given}{\mid}`, but yes.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you want the "column" to the right of the brace to be centered rather than left justified, which is what happens in all of the cases environments (at least, in all of the ones that I know about). To fix this this the OP's idea of using an array seems to be the way to go, but a few tweaks are needed.

- First, if you use `\left\{` then there has to be a matching `\right<delimiter>`. As there isn't a matching right delimiter, in this case, you can use `\right.`. Personally, I don't like the sizes that `\left....\right` produces so, instead, I have defined a macro `\Bigger` that will scale the following delimiter to the specified height in millimeters, which defaults to `7mm`. Except for the optional argument, this is similar to the `\bigl`, `\biggl`, `\Big` ... amsmath macros.
- Next, as the OP says, the rows of the array are too close together. You can adjust the spacing between rows using the optional argument to the `\\` command. So `\\[3mm]` will add an extra `3mm` between the rows, which seems about right.
- The `array` environment comes with padding, so there is too much space between the brace and the equations. You can remove the left-padding by adding `@{}` to the array specifications.
- I have added some punctuation.
- Finally, as suggested in the comments, `\mid` is better than `|`.

With these changes the MWE produces:

[image]

This is pretty close to the "ideal" image given at the top of the question. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% an ams-style operator for resizing delimiters
% Usage: \Bigger[, \Bigger[8][, \Bigger[10](, ...
\newcommand\Bigger[2][7]{\left#2\rule{0mm}{#1truemm}\right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
        P[\chi_{n+1}=j\mid\chi_{n}=i]=
        \Bigger[14]\{\begin{array}{@{}cl}
                \dfrac{N-i}{N}, & \text{si }j=i+1,\\[3mm]
                \dfrac{i}{N},   & \text{si }j=i-1,\\[3mm]
                0,              & \text{en otro caso}.
        \end{array}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a precise stylistic choice, so you should somehow make it the default by defining your own environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\makeatletter % some generic helpers
\newcommand{\LCASES}[1]{$\m@th\displaystyle{#1}$\hfil}
\newcommand{\CCASES}[1]{\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{#1}$\hfil}
\newcommand{\RCASES}[1]{\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{#1}$}
\makeatother

\newcases{ecases}{\quad}{\CCASES{##}}{\LCASES{##}}{\lbrace}{.}
\newcases{ecases*}{\quad}{\CCASES{##}}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P[\chi_{n+1}=j\mid\chi_{n}=i]=
\begin{ecases*}
  \frac{N-i}{N} & si $j=i+1$,\\
  \frac{i}{N}  & si $j=i-1$,\\
  0            & en otro caso.
\end{ecases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The `ecases` environment has the second column cells typeset in math mode, whereas in `ecases*` they're in text mode.

[image]

Say that the publisher to whom you submit your book tells you their editorial policy is to align left the cases. You can answer that it's really easy, because returning to the default just requires changing two lines:

```
\newcases{ecases}{\quad}{\LCASES{##}}{\LCASES{##}}{\lbrace}{.}
\newcases{ecases*}{\quad}{\LCASES{##}}{{##}\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
```

and you'd get

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find `\newcases` described in either the `amsmath` or `mathtools` manuals, however, @Werner has given a nice description of it in his answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27520/right-aligned-first-column-in-a-cases-environment.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it's not really documented and perhaps it should be expanded a bit to allow for avoiding low level functions (something like I did it my code).

Comment: Funny, I thought I had documented this back in the day but you are correct: it's not mentioned in the manual and should be.

Comment: @MortenHøgholm I'm quite sure that at some point in time the macro was documented. Maybe adding some boilerplate macros like above would make it friendlier.

Comment: @egreg I checked in my old sources and I didn't have it there either. Perhaps Lars has time to add it.

Answer (score 4):

Here, I use a TABstack for the cases.  In particular, a `\tabularCenterstack` allows the column alignments to be individually specified.  The baselineskip between cases can be simply set, as shown in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath% SETS STACKS IN MATH MODE
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}% DEFINE STYLE OF MATH STACKS
\setstackgap{L}{2.5\baselineskip}% SETS BASELINESKIP FOR LONG-STACKED LINES
\setstacktabulargap{2\tabcolsep}% DEFINES INTERCOLUMN GAP
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
        P[\chi_{n+1}=j|\chi_{n}=i]=
        \left\{
        \tabularCenterstack{cl}{
                \frac{N-i}{N}&\text{si }j=i+1\\
                \frac{i}{N}&\text{si }j=i-1\\
                0&\text{otro caso}
        }
        \right.
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would actually like to suggest that you *not* fully replicate the screenshot you've posted.

Instead, I'd go for a fully symmetrical look, in which the `=` symbols in the middle row to the right of the curly brace are perfectly aligned with the `=` symbols to the left. This may be achieved easily with the help of a judiciously constructed `\vphantom` term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' env.
\newcommand\zzz{\vphantom{\dfrac{\mathstrut}{\mathstrut}}} % to be inserted in all 3 rows
\begin{document}
\[
        \Pr[\, \chi^{}_{n+1}=j \mid \chi^{}_{n}=i \,]=
        \begin{dcases*}
                \frac{N-i}{N}\zzz & si $j=i+1$\\
                \frac{i}{N}\zzz   & si $j=i-1$\\
                0 \zzz            & otro caso
        \end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```