# Formatting piecewise function

Tags: equations, align

I need to write this

[image]

So far I started my code this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

 \begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
 u_t+2uu_x=0,              & x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0\\
 u(x,0)=g(x)=\begin{cases}
-1/2, & x<0,\\
1/2, & x>0.
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I get a similar result, which is not really in the same format.
The equation are not aligned according to the equal sign, and I have an extra open parenthesis which I don't know how to remove.

Comment: Seems you want `align*` instead of an equation environment. Put `&` before the equal signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  u_t+2uu_x   & = 0 ,\quad          x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0\\
u(x,0) = g(x) & = \begin{cases}
                -1/2, & x<0,\\
                 1/2, & x>0.
                    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

or maybe (stole from [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27520/right-aligned-first-column-in-a-cases-environment)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcases{mycases}{\quad}{%
  \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  u_t+2uu_x   & = 0 ,\quad          x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0\\
u(x,0) = g(x) & = \begin{mycases}
                -1/2, & x<0,\\
                 1/2, & x>0.
                    \end{mycases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I am not sure I understand the  \quad though

Comment: `\quad` determine space between variables or words in math environments (equations). I suggest you to read some introductory literature about latex, for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf and more advanced about math in latex https://www.researchgate.net/publication/295920492_More_Math_into_LaTeX_fifth_edition

Comment: I would align left, by moving the `&` at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: i only follow to op wish :-) , however i agree with you.